# Sobolev spaces of arclength curves.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $p>1$ and $I=(0,1)$. By Rellich--Kondrachov, if $u\in W^{k,p}(I;\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $k\geq 2$, then $u\in C^{1} ([0,1];\mathbb{R}^n)$ (and in fact the embedding $W^{k,p}(I) \to C^{1}([0,1])$ is compact). In particular, we may discuss pointwise evaluation of $u$ and $u'$.

In differential geometry, we identify smooth space curves with smooth functions with non-vanishing derivative, and in particular with a function with derivative taking values in the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

There are (at least) two things one might do to Sobolev-ify the set of such curves.
First, let \begin{equation} H^{k,p}_{\text{curve}} =\{u \in W^{k,p}(I; \mathbb{R}^n) : |u'(s)|=1 \text{ a.e. } s \in I\,\},
\end{equation}
and let 
\begin{equation}
W^{k,p}_{\text{curve}} = \overline{ \{u \in C^{\infty}([0,1]; \mathbb{R}^n): |u'(s)|=1 \text{ for all } s\in I \,\}  }.
\end{equation}
Here, I'm writing $\overline{A}$ for the closure of a set $A$ with respect to the strong topology on $W^{k,p}(I;\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I'd like to know: does $H_{\text{curve}}^{k,p}=W_{\text{curve}}^{k,p}$?

The nice thing about $H$ is that it is closed w.r.t. to the weak topology on $W^{k,p}(I;\mathbb{R}^n)$. The nice thing about $W$ is that smooth functions are dense with respect to the norm topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant $|u'(s)|=1$, not $|u(s)|=1$.

Let's focus on $v=u'$ and forget $u$ -- the regularity of $u$ is directly inferred from the regularity of $v$. You want to define a Sobolev space of maps $v:I\to S^{n-1}$, and observe that there are two reasonably looking definitions.

In the  [literature on Sobolev maps between manifolds](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=sobolev+maps+between+manifolds) one usually proceeds by isometrically embedding the target manifold $N$ into some $\mathbb R^d$ (this is always possible by Nash's theorem, and is given in your example with $S^{n-1}$), and then defines $N$-valued Sobolev maps as $\mathbb R^d$-valued Sobolev maps $v$ such that $v(x)\in N$ for a.e. $x$. This is  your $H$-definition, although I usually see the letter $W$ attached to it.

Then the natural question arises: are smooth maps dense in this Sobolev space? Sometimes yes, sometimes no. See  [Topology of Sobolev mappings II](http://www.math.nyu.edu/~fengbo/sobo2.pdf) by Hang and Lin, which corrects some incorrect statements in an important 1991 paper by Bethuel.

In your situation, the answer is yes. Two things help a lot:

1. There is a smooth retraction of a neighborhood of $S^{n-1}$ onto $S^{n-1}$, namely the map $\pi(x)=  x/|x|$.
2. Your Sobolev space consists of uniformly continuous maps.

In the presence of 1 and 2 every map from your $H$-space can be approximated by smooth maps via mollification-retraction. That is, given $v$ in $H^{k,p}$, we mollify it by convolution $v*\varphi_\epsilon$ and observe that, by uniform continuity of $v$, the difference $v-v*\varphi_\epsilon$ is small in the supremum norm. Therefore, $v*\varphi_\epsilon$ takes values in a small neighborhood of $S^{n-1}$ (a spherical shell). The  map $\pi\circ (v*\varphi_\epsilon)$ is the desired approximation. For details see, e.g., the proof of (more general) Theorem 5.2 in [Weakly Diﬀerentiable Mappings Between Manifolds](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/HIMO.pdf) by Hajlasz, Iwaniec,  Malý and Onninen.

Conclusion: smooth maps are dense in your $H$-space; therefore, the two spaces you defined are the same.

Comment: You're right about the typo. I've edited the question to reflect that.